# Trouble extracting scraped data with BS4

Tags: python

Im pretty new to coding so forgive me if my question seems basic or if I don't post this correctly. Im practising extracting names from a website and I want to put them into a list and then a .csv file. My code will print all the names but when I try to do anything else it only seems to see the last name. Ive tried all I know so hope you guys can help.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import civ

theurl = "http://business.cardiff.ac.uk/research/accounting-and-finance/faculty"

r = requests.get(theurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

print(soup.title.text)

for txt in soup.find_all("h1", {"class": "profile-title"}):
    name =  txt.text
    print(name)
```

After this I tried various ways to convert name into a list but only last name is seen.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you're posting code in the future, you can use the `{}` button in the editor to format it properly. It also helps to show us exactly what you're getting and what you want with sample output, instead of just describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the for loop, where you keep overwriting the `name` object. Try this:

```
name = []

for txt in soup.find_all("h1",{"class":"profile-title"}):
    name.append(txt.text)
```

This creates an empty list and then successively appends each of the names found in the `profile-title` elements.

Comment: Thank you so much Nils. I was almost there!

Comment: No worries - if this actually solved the question it'd be good if you could accept the answer to close it.